# Breaking a loop but "completing" the generator

Tags: python

_

consider the following example:

```
def generator(iterable):
    print('Start')
    for item in iterable: yield item
    print('Stop')

for x in generator(range(10)):
    print(x)
    if x==3: break
    print(x)
```

whose output is

```
Start
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
```

Python of course does exactly what it's being told. The generator is not called again after x==3 and so "Stop" is never printed. The generator abstraction is reasonable. However, in this case I'm actually trying to achieve a subtly different kind of abstraction, kind of like decorating a loop to make it a customized loop. Some code should run before the loop, some for each iteration, and some after the loop, even in case of `break`.

Of course I do not rely on this exact abstraction to make my program work, but it would be nice. Does anyone have any good ideas for this case?

Kind regards.

Comment: So you mean that you want to get the output with `'Stop'`

Comment: Write a context manager.

Comment: Can you give more context? Although this is conceptually interesting it feels like an XY problem

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I do not understand what you mean by an XY problem, but I can think of a few cases where this abstraction might come in handy. As a simplified context, consider a progress bar which for each iteration overwrites the last line (not using ncurses). When the loop is finished you want to write an \n, regardless of how it finished, such that the next time something is printed it appears on a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generator is a good abstraction for a loop, but for before-and-after code Python has another abstraction – context managers and the 'with' statement. You can use those those two together, e.g. this way:

```
class generator_context:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __enter__(self):
        print('Start')
        for item in self.iterable: yield item

    def __exit__(self, e_type, e_value, e_traceback):
        if e_type is None:
            print('Stop')

with generator_context(range(10)) as generator:
    for x in generator:
        print(x)
        if x==3: break
        print(x)
```

Comment: Ah, yes! This is actually the abstraction I was thinking about. It's really a composition of two abstractions and not one, since the user of `generator_context` would have to use both a `with` statement and the resulting generator. While it would've been more convenient (in this case) to not have to write the `with` statement I see that this is indeed a very pythonic way to do it (and besides, composition is not a bad idea).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could put your generator inside a try > finally.

```
def generator(iterable):
    try:
        print('Start')
        for item in iterable: yield item
    finally:
        print('Stop')
```

This makes what is inside finally always execute.

Comment: Pay attention, finally doesn't always execute, only when the code inside try reaches the end or throws. This code relies on garbage collection of generator object, so if other references to it exist, "Stop" will not be called right after loop break. You better stop generator explicitly with `gen.close()` call

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, a context manager will probably do what you are looking for. Here's one that auto-closes the generator (which makes sense because `"stop"` was printed as an indication that there are no more values).

```
class my_generator:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.g = (x for x in iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.g

    def __enter__(self):
        print('start')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, trace):
        self.g.close() 

        # do whatever cleanup is necessary in case of exception
        print('stop')
```

Usage:

```
>>> with my_generator([1,2,3]) as g:
...     for x in g:
...         print(x)
...         if x == 2:
...             break
... 
start
1
2
stop
>>> list(g)
[]
```